# How to configure/add additional locale to JasperReports Server 6.3.0?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have added additional locale according to the Server Administration Guide, i.e.
[image: applicationContext-security.xml]

I've restarted tomcat. However the added locale is still not present in the output options in the schedule

[image: output locale]

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed probably the chapters before this settings description, called **Creating a locale**.

First you need to create

- language properties files for several parts of JasperServer and translate all JasperServer texts
- create a resource bundle out of those properties
- change date and time formats accordingly to the new locale

When all this exists, *then* you can add another entry in the list.

Right now you only added the list entry but JasperServer checks for all the other stuff and since it is probably not available, it won't show the new locale.